# Circular Progress Bars in IOS

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, ios4, ios6

I want to create a circular progress bar like the following:

[image: Circular progress bar]

How can I do that using Objective-C and Cocoa?

How I started doing it was creating a UIView and editing the drawRect, but I am bit lost. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Just as an aside you can include images in your question.  It saves us jumping to another website to look at them.

Comment: Only users with a high enough rep can include images, not sure 31 is high enough.

Comment: @WDuk it must be a low level as I am sure I saw someone with a sub 100 rep posting images.  I just checked meta-stack overflow, and they suggest that a rep of 10 is the minimum for posting images.

Comment: Done it myself, no worries.

Comment: This is exactly what u looking for: https://github.com/marshluca/AudioPlayer You can also refer to some Sources : https://github.com/lipka/LLACircularProgressView

Comment: You can check my library: https://github.com/PavelKatunin/DownloadButton It contains `PKCircleProgressView` which could be useful for you.

Comment: Check out this control – https://github.com/maxkonovalov/MKRingProgressView It is highly customizable and is able to produce results like this: [![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8OQIi.png)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8OQIi.png)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The basic concept is to use the `UIBezierPath` class to your advantage. You are able to draw arcs, which achieve the effect you're after. I've only had half an hour or so to have a crack at this, but my attempt is below.

Very rudimentary, it simply uses a stroke on the path, but here we go. You can alter/modify this to your exact needs, but the logic to do the arc countdown will be very similar.

In the view class:

```
@interface TestView () {
    CGFloat startAngle;
    CGFloat endAngle;
}

@end

@implementation TestView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        // Determine our start and stop angles for the arc (in radians)
        startAngle = M_PI * 1.5;
        endAngle = startAngle + (M_PI * 2);

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Display our percentage as a string
    NSString* textContent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.percent];

    UIBezierPath* bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

    // Create our arc, with the correct angles
    [bezierPath addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(rect.size.width / 2, rect.size.height / 2) 
                          radius:130 
                      startAngle:startAngle
                        endAngle:(endAngle - startAngle) * (_percent / 100.0) + startAngle
                       clockwise:YES];

    // Set the display for the path, and stroke it
    bezierPath.lineWidth = 20;
    [[UIColor redColor] setStroke];
    [bezierPath stroke];

    // Text Drawing
    CGRect textRect = CGRectMake((rect.size.width / 2.0) - 71/2.0, (rect.size.height / 2.0) - 45/2.0, 71, 45);
    [[UIColor blackColor] setFill];
    [textContent drawInRect: textRect withFont: [UIFont fontWithName: @"Helvetica-Bold" size: 42.5] lineBreakMode: NSLineBreakByWordWrapping alignment: NSTextAlignmentCenter];
}
```

For the view controller:

```
@interface ViewController () {    
    TestView* m_testView;
    NSTimer* m_timer;
}

@end

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // Init our view
    [super viewDidLoad];
    m_testView = [[TestView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    m_testView.percent = 100;
    [self.view addSubview:m_testView];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // Kick off a timer to count it down
    m_timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(decrementSpin) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)decrementSpin
{
    // If we can decrement our percentage, do so, and redraw the view
    if (m_testView.percent > 0) {
        m_testView.percent = m_testView.percent - 1;
        [m_testView setNeedsDisplay];
    }
    else {
       [m_timer invalidate];
       m_timer = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: do you know how I can than put the background images to make it look like the picture above?

Comment: How do I get this to have ronnded ends?

Comment: @Siriss Have you tried changing `lineCapStyle` on the `UIBezierPath`?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, i finally figured it out, just forgot to come back and update this.

Comment: Great sample code.  I was able to create exactly what I needed based on this sample.  Thanks!!

Comment: Great post, thank you! Some remarks for absolute beginners:  <br/>
- `[self.view addSubview:m_webView];` should of course be `[self.view addSubview: m_testView];`
- TestView.h should look like this:  <br/>
`#import <UIKit/UIKit.h> 
@interface UICircle : UIView 
@property (nonatomic) double percent;
@end`

Comment: @WDUK : great sample code helped a lot thanx. I want to draw a circle which is supposed to be like filling like a circular progress-bar exactly like  like above image. i could draw a circle but when i try to draw on it with 25 or 50 % progress the new one overwrites the previous one. How do i draw 2 circles?

Answer (score 23):

My example with magic numbers (for better understanding):

```
  CAShapeLayer *circle = [CAShapeLayer layer];
  circle.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(29, 29) radius:27 startAngle:-M_PI_2 endAngle:2 * M_PI - M_PI_2 clockwise:YES].CGPath;
  circle.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
  circle.strokeColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
  circle.lineWidth = 4;

  CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
  animation.duration = 10;
  animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
  animation.fromValue = @(0);
  animation.toValue = @(1);
  animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
  [circle addAnimation:animation forKey:@"drawCircleAnimation"];

  [imageCircle.layer.sublayers makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperlayer)];
  [imageCircle.layer addSublayer:circle];
```

Comment: how would you get the lead CGPoint as it animates around?

Comment: @whyoz, I used method **bezierPathWithArcCenter** that draws arc at center!

Comment: well, I know that!  Haha, I'm trying to get more info outta ya if you have an idea how to do that, if I wanted to track that point as it moved around center.  So get the "startPoint" in the form of a CGPoint from the startAngle's first point..thought there might be a quick property to grab..

Comment: @whyoz, You want track **CGPoint** in real time? I don't know easy way to do this. But you can calculate this point. Something like this: 1 Get current angle - [current time seconds - start time seconds] * 360 / [duration seconds]. 2 We know angle and radius. We need calculate point on circle. x = radius * sin(current angle), y = radius * cos(current angle). I hope this will help you.

Comment: Can we show this animation with progress value instead of time duration?

Comment: @UserDev, yes, you can update CAShapeLayer object every time when your progress will be changed.

Comment: @Darkngs, nice code, but i want circle based on percent. how to do it.

Answer (score 21):

I have implemented a simple library for iOS doing just that. It's based on the UILabel class so you can display whatever you want inside your progress bar, but you can also leave it empty.

Once initialized, you only have one line of code to set the progress :

`[_myProgressLabel setProgress:(50/100))];`

The library is named [KAProgressLabel](http://alexiscreuzot.com/KAProgressLabel/)

Comment: Thanks, to be fair there is another very good one: https://github.com/danielamitay/DACircularProgress

Comment: It would be very nice if you could use 2 images for the circular progress bar

Answer (score 13):

You can check out my lib  [MBCircularProgressBar](http://github.com/matibot/MBCircularProgressBar)

[image]

Comment: there is a way to add your library to Xcode project without pod? thanks

Comment: Of course, Just copy the Layer and View files to your project

Comment: How to fill complete progress bar?

Comment: Is there any progress change delegate available ? I mean one can give a time of 40s to reach the full progress value 100 and if somebody wants to do something when it progress to 60 % like that

Answer (score 12):

For **Swift** use this,

```
let circle = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0, 100, 100))

circle.layoutIfNeeded()

let centerPoint = CGPoint (x: circle.bounds.width / 2, y: circle.bounds.width / 2)
let circleRadius : CGFloat = circle.bounds.width / 2 * 0.83

var circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: centerPoint, radius: circleRadius, startAngle: CGFloat(-0.5 * M_PI), endAngle: CGFloat(1.5 * M_PI), clockwise: true    )

let progressCircle = CAShapeLayer()
progressCircle.path = circlePath.CGPath
progressCircle.strokeColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
progressCircle.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
progressCircle.lineWidth = 1.5
progressCircle.strokeStart = 0
progressCircle.strokeEnd = 0.22

circle.layer.addSublayer(progressCircle)

self.view.addSubview(circle)
```

Reference: See [Here](http://notebookheavy.com/2014/07/30/ios-7-style-progress-meter-in-swift/).

Answer (score 10):

**Swift 3 use this,**

CAShapeLayer with Animation : Continue with  Zaid Pathan ans.

```
    let circle = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))

    circle.layoutIfNeeded()

    var progressCircle = CAShapeLayer()

    let centerPoint = CGPoint (x: circle.bounds.width / 2, y: circle.bounds.width / 2)
    let circleRadius : CGFloat = circle.bounds.width / 2 * 0.83

    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: centerPoint, radius: circleRadius, startAngle: CGFloat(-0.5 * M_PI), endAngle: CGFloat(1.5 * M_PI), clockwise: true    )

    progressCircle = CAShapeLayer ()
    progressCircle.path = circlePath.cgPath
    progressCircle.strokeColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
    progressCircle.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    progressCircle.lineWidth = 2.5
    progressCircle.strokeStart = 0
    progressCircle.strokeEnd = 1.0
     circle.layer.addSublayer(progressCircle)


    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    animation.fromValue = 0
    animation.toValue = 1.0
    animation.duration = 5.0
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
     progressCircle.add(animation, forKey: "ani")

    self.view.addSubview(circle)
```

Comment: What is that 0.83 for? Is width / 2 not enough for circular radius?

Answer (score 1):

Here a **Swift** example of how to make a simple, not closed(to leave space for long numbers) circular progress bar with rounded corners and animation.

[open_circular_progress_bar.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwPNH.jpg)

```
func drawBackRingFittingInsideView(lineWidth: CGFloat, lineColor: UIColor) {

    let halfSize:CGFloat = min( bounds.size.width/2, bounds.size.height/2)

    let desiredLineWidth:CGFloat = lineWidth

    let circle = CGFloat(Double.pi * 2)

    let startAngle = CGFloat(circle * 0.1)

    let endAngle = circle – startAngle

    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(

        arcCenter: CGPoint(x:halfSize, y:halfSize),

        radius: CGFloat( halfSize – (desiredLineWidth/2) ),

        startAngle: startAngle,

        endAngle: endAngle,

        clockwise: true)

    let shapeBackLayer = CAShapeLayer()

        shapeBackLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath

        shapeBackLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

        shapeBackLayer.strokeColor = lineColor.cgColor

        shapeBackLayer.lineWidth = desiredLineWidth

        shapeBackLayer.lineCap = .round

    layer.addSublayer(shapeBackLayer)

}
```

And the animation function.

```
 func animateCircle(duration: TimeInterval) {

    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: “strokeEnd”)

    animation.duration = duration

    animation.fromValue = 0

    animation.toValue = 1

    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.linear)        

    shapeLayer.strokeEnd = 1.0

    shapeLayer.add(animation, forKey: “animateCircle”)

}
```

There is a good [blog](https://tripexbud.com/circular-progress-view-for-the-ios-apps/) with examples.