# timer with animation

Tags: iphone, ios6, nstimer

Can anyone show me some reference for the animation in Countdown timer in iOS, I implement the timer, I Want to make an animation like in the image, is it possible?

[image]

Comment: yes it is possible. You have to draw the arc after the specified time mentioned in the NSTimer

Comment: @PranjalBikashDas Any refrence is available ???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573676/circular-progress-bars-in-ios

Comment: @PranjalBikashDas what is self.percent in tat  link??

Answer (score 0):

You need to subclass UIView and override drawInRect: method get the current drawing context and draw the path you want and fill the path. Refer [Quatz Core drawing](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=drawing%20using%20quatz%20core&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Fdocumentation%2Fgraphicsimaging%2Fconceptual%2Fdrawingwithquartz2d%2Fdq_layers%2Fdq_layers.html&ei=8Cv1UOadEsr_rAeKyYHIAg&usg=AFQjCNFo2pyYtE9SSLJG2YklO_vTCKLdhA&bvm=bv.41018144,d.bmk)