# Create loading-circle

Tags: ios, objective-c, draw, updates

I'd like to draw a circle part by part. The circle should act as a loading-circle and should update itself after something is completed and should colorize a part of the circle.

I've tried already to do that with a for-loop in the `drawRect-method`, but the circle doesn't update properly.

Are there any important methods I have to use to update the circle "smooth"?

Comment: you want a radial progress bar you mean ? if yes, this might help you:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573676/circular-progress-bars-in-ios

Answer (score 1):

You can check this class: [HKCircularProgressView](https://github.com/Harmek/HKCircularProgressView)

it should give you a hint on what to do. I'm sure that if you search for the animating properties in objective-c you will find what you are after:) e.g. [animating-custom-layer-properties-by-rob-napier/](http://cocoaheads.tv/animating-custom-layer-properties-by-rob-napier/)