# How to make a curved progress bar around a circular UIView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, progress-bar

I want to make a circular progress bar such as that, how to animate its resizing and properties (shape, colour, width, etc.) as well.

I am trying to make it around a circular transparent view.

Where to start?

Does anyone has a sample code?

[image]

Comment: Might be your solution is here please follow this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573676/circular-progress-bars-in-ios

Comment: Please don't ask for spoon-feeding. Try something of your own and if that doesn't work we are always there to help you.

Comment: Hence, all I asked for was "Where to start?" I already Googled it but all examples are kind of stand alone and nothing seemed appropriate to be used in a large system with OOP. Please stop assuming everyone is asking to be spoon fed.

Comment: You can follow this also - https://github.com/stablekernel/STKSpinnerView

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no substitute for learning, however a little help never goes a miss, so here are snippets of code that will accomplish the task for you.

The concept is to use a CAShapeLayer and a UIBezierPath and progress is simply setting the strokeEnd  propertie of the UIBezierPath. You'll need to declare a CAShapeLayer and set its properties. We'll call this our progressLayer. (i'm not going to provide complete code, simply direction and samples for you to put together.)

```
    // setup progress layer
    // N.B borderWidth is a float representing a value used as a margin. 
    // pathwidth is the width of the progress path
    // obviously progressBounds is a CGRect specifying the Layer's Bounds
    [self.progressLayer setFrame:progressBounds];
    UIBezierPath *progressPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(bounds), CGRectGetMidY(bounds)) radius:(bounds.size.height - self.borderWidth - self.pathWidth   ) / 2 startAngle: (5* -M_PI / 12)  endAngle: (2.0 * M_PI - 7 * M_PI /12)   clockwise:YES];
     self.progressLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
     self.progressLayer.lineWidth = 6.0f ;
     self.progressLayer.path = progressPath.CGPath;
     self.progressLayer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5f, 0.5f);
     self.progressLayer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
     self.progressLayer.position = CGPointMake(self.layer.frame.size.width / 2 - self.borderWidth / 2, self.layer.frame.size.height / 2 - self.borderWidth/2);
    [self.progressLayer setStrokeEnd:0.0f];
```

You will obviously need to add progressLayer to your view hierarchie

Then you will need a simple animation to progress the bar;

```
    // updateInterval is a float specifying the duration of the animation.
    // progress is a float storing the, well, progress. 
    // newProgress is a float 

    [self.progressLayer setStrokeEnd:newProgress];
    CABasicAnimation *strokeEndAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
    strokeEndAnimation.duration = updateInterval;
    [strokeEndAnimation setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];
    strokeEndAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
    strokeEndAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    strokeEndAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.progress];
    strokeEndAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:newProgress];
    self.progress = newProgress;
    [self.progressLayer addAnimation:strokeEndAnimation forKey:@"progressStatus"];
```

in your image above, the un-progressed path is nothing more than a second fully stroked layer behind the progressLayer

oh, and one final point, you'll find that the Circle progresses Clockwise. If you take the time to learn what's happening here, you'll figure out how to set progress Anti Clockwise.

Good Luck ...

Answer (score 1):

You can also check out my lib [MBCircularProgressBar](http://github.com/matibot/MBCircularProgressBar), it also shows how to animate with and how to make it customizable from the Interface Builder. You can make it transparent by using transparent colors.

http://raw.github.com/matibot/MBCircularProgressBar/master/Readme/example.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Here's a great, short tutorial on how to make this: http://www.tommymaxhanks.com/circular-progress-view/

You will need to learn a bit of Core Graphics in order to accomplish this in the way you want (the author used a gradient in the implementation, you may want to change that.), but it's worth it if you want to do cool stuff like this on the iPhone!

I think even more helpful is the example code, which is hosted here: https://github.com/mweyamutsvene/THControls/tree/master/CircularProgressView