# Circular progress bar with circular UILabel

Tags: ios, user-interface

So I found this cool UI design on dribble https://dribbble.com/shots/1021040-UI-User-Profile-Page and I want to use that header section (profile picture, level, and right info). The problem I'm stumped on is the progress bar. So I've been experimenting with UIBezierPaths for the bar part (thanks to help from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573676/circular-progress-bars-in-ios)) but I can't figure out how to do the same for the UILabel. Like the part in the UI above where it says Level 12. If you notice the letters itself are curved along progress bar. Is that possible or do I have to make static images (there are only 30 levels for what I will be using it for and the circle is showing the progress from level 0 to level 30).

Comment: Look into CoreText for editing the text. It should be able to accomplish what you want to do depending on how down and dirty you want to get.  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Overview/Overview.html

Answer (score 0):

we can do this by using `TextKit`,`UITextView` `exclusionPaths`

for more info and example code have look at [TextKit Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50151/text-kit-tutorial)