# Circular countdown timer

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I have been desparetely searching for it but couldn't find it.
I need to have a circular countdown timer for 1 minute which reduces time like `60 sec,59 sec, 58 sec.....,2 sec,1 sec,0 sec`

Using a progressbarview appearance like in this ex ([[Circular Progress Bars in IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573676/circular-progress-bars-in-ios][1])) instead starts from `1 sec,2 sec,3 sec..58 sec, 59 sec, 60 sec` which is starting from forward.

How can I get the appearance which reduces time from 60 to 0 sec?

Any ideas/help would be highly appreciated

Comment: can you show  your code?

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, you should start with percent = 0 and make an "increment" function, adding 1 until you reach 100.