# How to use circular progressbar in UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I need to show progress of audio playing in uitableviewcell . Can you guide me how can I make it possible ?

[image]

I need to show the progress like below picture :

[image]

What should I do ??

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Look at this answer, it might help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573676/circular-progress-bars-in-ios

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @Janmenjaya . I will check and let you know the result .

Comment: There's a very nice Swift library I'm using currently for the same purpose - https://github.com/ConfianceLabs/CLTimer ...why reinvent the wheel :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using `UIActivityIndicator`.
Use this link for reference.
https://github.com/c99koder/lastfm-iphone